# Rails: How to write your own authentication without using has_secure_password

Tags: validation, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app Admin creates user with email only. When user tries to set password,it does not work. below code works only when i remove validations.

```
def password=(password_str)
  @password = password_str 
  self.password_salt   = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
  self.password_digest = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password_str, password_salt)
end

def authenticate(password)
  password.present? && password_digest.present? && password_digest == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
end

validates :password             , length: { minimum: 6 }, :if => :setting_password?
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true        , :if => :setting_password?

def setting_password?
 self.password || self.password_confirmation
end
```

1) i can set password only when i comment the validations on password

2) password_confirmation field saves the password as it is..

Comment: did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a useful solution for most types of authentication (and what I use most of the time) but if you really need to write authentication without has_secure_password Ryan Bates' Railscasts has [got you covered](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch?view=asciicast).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

for rails 4 this is different (no more attr_accessors on models), modifying this we need a attr_reader :password and a way of setting the password and password_confirmation so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end

  ##
  # accessor
  def password=(unencrypted_password)
    unless unencrypted_password.blank?
      @password = unencrypted_password
    end
  end

  ##
  # accessor
  def password_confirmation=(unencrypted_password)
    @password_confirmation = unencrypted_password
  end
end
```

However, if we look at the has_secure_password method [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c31b900221cb15386235145b4a809a02abee8df9/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb) we see that the business logic is in the password=(unencrypted) rather than a before save callback (which makes obvious sense) I feel that that's probably the cleanest way to execute this.

Answer (score 2):

Hey checkout the rails 4 tutorial here this might give you some ideas. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#cha-modeling_users

It goes through user authentication with bcrypt.